# want: rtf editor with "collapsable" sections; thinking: using StyledEditorKit in java's swing system

Tags: java

this is the product (for my own use) that i desire: 
- an RTF editor, (much like wordpad or the very good, free RTF editor i use called PolyEdit Lite) 
- but with the ability to collapse sections of the text [and the ability to nest these things], just like how you can do this in many text editors used to program. (ie, many such editors for java or C will give you the option to collapse or expand any section of your source code that is enclosed in the { and } characters)

i looked on the internet for such an application, but i could not find one. 
but i discovered that java's swing system has a built-in RTF editor of sorts. looking through the java tutorials (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html), though, suggests that this is a really LARGE undertaking!

the furthest idea i got, while reading those tutorials, is to use a StyledEditorKit, which (supposedly) can alter the way the data (the "document") is displayed on the screen (ie the "view"). but how to actually control that view (ie, how to make little + or - symbols i can click on, etc) is something i don't know if it's even possible to do!

it would be cool for me to learn, though. i have some experience in java, but nothing about swing.

(if i could learn to do this idea i'm wanting to do, then there are other ideas i'd implement, too.
` [the reason i want this "RTF editor with collapsable sections" application is to help me with the creative process of brainstorming and organizing ideas. there are other features i'd like to add if i could that would help with brainstorming etc, such as being able to set an additional rectangular area of the document that i could type in (much like in Microsoft OneNote or Microsoft Publisher), perhaps how you might put in a rectangular picture in a document, except in this case you could actually type in this rectangular area].
)

so my questions are:
1) do you think it's even possible to create the application i'm wanting (ie an RTF editor with collapsable sections) using java's swing abilities?
2) if so, do you have any guidance on where on the internet i could look, so i could learn what i have to learn?

thanks for any of your ideas. i've been thinking about doing this for over a year, but am only asking now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [jedit](http://www.jedit.org/). It is a general open source editor in java. They list folding and rtf as its features.

If you want to look at a simpler but still powerful editor in java see [RText](http://fifesoft.com/rtext/index.php). I don't know whether it can fold or handle RTF but it is an actively developed editor with emphasizes easy to read code.

To your questions:

1. of course it is possible
2. have a look a the source of one of these editors for ideas.